# Dynamics of particles and fields on the torus: references

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, resource-recommendations, topology, noethers-theorem

In some situations (e.g. [molecular dynamics situations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/566778/226902), [Euclidean QFT](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807108), [cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/177799/226902)), a common trick to eliminate boundary effects or to provide an infrared cutoff is to use [periodic boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_boundary_conditions). Therefore, I am trying to understand the implications of the global [torus topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus) on the system's dynamics.

**What is the effect of the global topology of the space manifold** (or [base space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/469666/226902)) **on**, e.g., **the symmetries, the conservation laws and the equations of motion?** (for fields, including gauge fields, or even classical point particles and/or usual QM [see this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5773/226902)).

I am particularly interested in spacetimes of the kind $T^n\times\mathbb{R}$, where $T^n$ is the flat n-dimensional torus (space) and time is just the usual thing (i.e. not "thermal" fields, where time lives on the circle $T^1$, see e.g. [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9807108) and [this example with fermions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/798123/226902)).

**Specific question:** Are there dedicated references (reviews, books) that discuss the Noether theorem, conservation laws and, generally, the dynamics of a system on the torus? (or manifolds other than the usual Galielaian or Minkowski space).

**Concrete example:** The flat torus is [not symmetric under rotations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3240765/532409), so there should be no conservation of angular momentum for a system on the torus. However, a point particle on the flat torus "looks like" a particle on the plane (locally) and the Noether theorem seems to apply. Where does the global topology (that for the torus is defined by boundary conditions, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/732434/226902) question) enter the Noether theorem (or conservation laws)?

Comment: Note: the two answers https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/732521/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/299124/226902 are quite useful. Magnetic field on the torus: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/693806/226902. Moreover, the Ehrenfest theorem is more subtle on the torus: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267835/226902.

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/802042/226902 (molecular dynamics on the torus)

Comment: Ewald summation: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/605842/226902

Comment: Charges on compact manifolds without boundaries (like the torus): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137819/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461259/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604217/226902